# I want java to create a new file with ...new PrintStream... it all works fine, but I can't find the file in my project

Tags: java, eclipse

So I have a simple code similar to a digital math test (only 1 question though). I want the program to scan what I type in the input window, and the print the results whether I was right or wrong in a new text file. The problem is I can not find the text file in my project in eclipse, instead I have to locate my projects folder and find the .txt file there instead. Is it possible to make the .txt file visible inside my project in eclipse? Thanks! ... also, how do you do quote marks inside of quote marks in java? I mean like "You answered "500" ".

```
package Default;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MathTest {
  public static void main(String args[])
                throws FileNotFoundException {
    String Canswer = "270";
    String X;

    PrintStream file = new  PrintStream(new File("Test results.txt"));
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("This is a test, please answer the question correctly.");
    System.out.println("What is 50*50/100-20+(800/20) ?");

    X = scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println("That concludes this test, your test results will be available"
        + " in ´Test results.");

    if (X.equals(Canswer)) {
      file.println("You answered " + X);
      file.println("That is correct, well done!");
    } else {
      file.println("You answered " + X + ".");
      file.println("The correct answer was " + Canswer);
      file.println("You have failed this test.");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: blocks of code on stackoverflow are formatted by having 4 spaces in front of every line. Back ticks are for inline code only. When posting/editing, there's a useful "how to format" box on the right that tells you the syntax you can use here.

Comment: escape the quote with a backslash like String s = "Answer is \"500\"";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first instinct about not being able to see your file is simply you didn't refresh your project. Try right-clicking your project > clicking "Refresh" and see if your text file appears. Eclipse doesn't update your file system in real-time, so you must refresh your project to see any updates.

For the quotes, you must escape the quotes with a preceding forward slash, like so:

```
System.out.println("She said, \"I don't eat vegetables.\"");
```

That will output:

She said, "I don't eat vegetables."

Comment: Looks like I made a rookie mistake, I kept trying to refresh my src folder, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Drop the file in your project base dir in eclipse and then access the file using just the name.

Answer (score 0):

You need the specified file inside of the project directory folder (outside of the src folder), then access it by name (and the type, if necessary).

The only time you need to specify a path is if you store your files in sub-directories such as "resources/images/player/player_forward.png", or if it's not in the .jar.

Also, in order to show quotes within a String in Java, place a backslash before the quote mark.

For example:

```
String quote = "\"Life is like a box of chocolates.\"";
```

It will print out:

"Life is like a box of chocolates."

Also, it's just like using the new line character:

```
String text = "Hello.\nHow is your day?"
```

That will print:

"Hello.
How is your day?"

If you want to print out an actual backslash, you do a backslash before the backslash.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the OS you're in, `PrintStream file = new  PrintStream(new File("Test results.txt"));` may be a problem due to spaces. That said, why are you using a PrintStream rather than a BufferedWriter?